# Implementing Database Error Handling in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling

I am creating a webapp using codeigniter. I want to implement a error handling function. Say for example if I call a method of a model, and if an error occurs in that method, the error handler comes into action to return some pre-formatted string.

I was thinking of creating something like MY_Model, which every model class extends. Then, I can add the error handler in MY_Model class. But whether this can be done is beyond me right now. (yes I am a newbie at this)

Any enlightening ideas will help.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I tend to do is return an array instead of a boolean. This array contains 2 keys, 'return' and 'error'.

In case of an error this array will look like the following:

```
array('return' => FALSE, 'error' => 'Some error')
```

In case of a successful execution this array will look like the following:

```
array('return' => TRUE)
```

The controller then verifies these results and if there's an error it will display the one set in the 'error' key.

Comment: @Yorick - That's how you have implemented the error handling. I want to know where to implement it?

Comment: Those arrays are returned by the model to the controller which then validates it.

Comment: Does that mean putting a try catch inside every method of model, so that when an exception is caught, the array is returned??